# Python CMD module: Shell quits after -h

Tags: python, shell, cmd, argparse

this is my first question here so I'm sorry if any mistakes were made.

I'm making a shell in python using CMD with some Youtube features, I have it almost done, functions work propertly but for some reason the shell quits after I try to [command] -h (I'm using argparse for this)

Here is an example of what happens for you to see:

[As you can see, arguments help gets printed but then it quits the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMMa4.png)

If I input correct arguments shell keeps opened as desired.

Here's the code of getSongUrl function:

```
    def do_getSongUrl(self, arg):
    """given a name, returns a list with all the videos and their URLs"""

    args = parser_getSongUrl.parse_args(arg.split())

    song = args.song

    song_str = ' '.join(word for word in song)

    print("Searching: " + song_str)
    print("Limiting results to: " + str(args.limit))

    res = musictools.get_song_urls(song_str)

    for i in range(args.limit):
        for (song_urls, song_titles) in res:
            print(song_titles + ":")
            print(song_urls)
            print("")
```

The parser for this functions is defined before the CMD class, this is how I saw every example, here's the code for the parser:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Shell parsers handler')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

parser_getSongUrl = subparsers.add_parser("getSongUrl")

parser_getSongUrl.add_argument("-s", "--song", help="Name of the song", type=str, required="true", nargs="+")
parser_getSongUrl.add_argument("-l", "--limit",  help="Limits the output", type=int, default=10)
```

Thank you in advance for any kind of help. I'm still new to python and would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: that's builtin in `argparse`. see the option that it has added before yours: `-h/--help`. but why do you have a problem with that?

Comment: Do not post text as a picture, copy-paste it instead.

Answer (score 0):

What does it say on the `-h` line?

```
show this help message and exit
```

With `subparsers` you can get several levels of help, one for the main parser and one for each subparser.

This is normal behavior with `-h`, `--help` in command lines, whether using shell commands (e.g. `ls -h`) or scripts that use `argparse`.

```
parser_getSongUrl.print_help()
parser.print_help()
parser.print_usage()
```

will show the help without exiting.  I often use that when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Exiting the program is the default action after printing help:

```
class _HelpAction(Action):
    <...>
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        parser.print_help()
        parser.exit()

class ArgumentParser(_AttributeHolder, _ActionsContainer): 
    <...>
    def exit(self, status=0, message=None):
        if message:
            self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
        _sys.exit(status)
```

`exit()` is also called from `ArgumentParser.error()` which is called when e.g. unrecognised arguments are seen.

**So, you can change this behaviour by replacing your parser's `exit()`**. You don't want to override `_HelpAction`'s logic instead because you do want the parser to end its work and return control to your console loop (rather than the command execution code) after printing help or seeing an error. E.g. by raising some specific exception.

**Alternatively, you can trap `SystemExit` in your console loop** and treat it as an end-of-command.